# CSS- div on div - can't use the background div everywhere

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, leaflet

I am not very confident with CSS, and I would just like to use a leaflet map and on top of it, add filters card.

The card is on top of the map, this is great but for some reason I cannot use the map in the background (zoom/unzoom, select point...)

[image: map layers illustration]

The code is very simple; here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="container-map">
  <div class="map-background">
    <lfmap></lfmap>
  </div>
  <div class="map-filter">
    <racesfilter class="animated fadeIn"></racesfilter>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.container-map {
  position: relative;
}

.map-background,
.map-filter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.map-background {
  z-index: 10;
}

.map-filter {
  z-index: 100;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

`racesfilter` is pretty simple as well:

```html
<div class="card-criterias" style="width: 30rem;">
  <div>
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.card-criterias {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

Comment: if you don't need to perform any mouse action inside the card you can add the property `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Add `background: red` to your `.map-filter` and you'll see that most probably the filter-div is bigger than the white card, so you are clicking on the map-filter, instead of on the map. For starters you could replace `padding-left: 10%; padding-top: 5%` with `margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 5%`

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, replacing padding by margin did the job. i guess I need to read about it, I didn't know the difference.